# PHP namespaces : \My\Namespace or My\Namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.3

- `My\Namespace`

  - `\My\Namespace`

So, which one should I use, I see the [php documentation](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) uses mostly `My\Namespace`.

But it is said that `\My\Namespace` is better, because non ambiguous, whereas `My\Namespace` could be resolved as `\RandomNamespace\My\Namespace`.

I've started to wonder about this after reading **there is an issue in Doctrine 2 about this** : "[Please replace 'Doctrine\XXX\YYY' with '\Doctrine\XXX\YYY' in code and document](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1025)"

So, do you have any more information about this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no different than using relative vs absolute file/uri paths and will come down to preference. However, unlike absolute paths, I agree with the less ambiguous `\My\Namespace` because it will never break, where relative namespaces could.

Namespace aliases, via `use` add to the abiguity of relative namespace names. For example, I can say: `use \PDO as YourMom` and later call `YourMom` within the code. Is it `\PDO`, `\YourMOM`, or `YourMom` that it is being called? Obviously the alias wins and is resolved to `\PDO`, assuming there is no conflict, but it makes code hard to follow.

**Edit**

Code example to prove abiguity is possible. Make sure you see the global **[fallback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php)** applied if a namespace is unqualified.

As mentioned by @netcoder, it is impossible to be abiguous during the **declaration** of a namespace. Thus, `namespace My` and `namespace \My` (or swap any other namespace declaration below) are 100% identical as and declaration fully qualifies a namespace.

```
namespace My
{
}

namespace My\Other
{
    use Bob; // Resolves to \My\Other\Bob
}

namespace My\Other\NS
{
    use \My\Other as Other;
    use Other\NS as Duh; // This resolves to \My\Other\NS
}

namespace My\Other\Bob
{
    use Other\NS as Duh; // This resolves to \Other\NS becuase the namespace doesn't exist inside \My\Other\Bob
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the namespace declaration itself it makes no difference. This declaration defines always a full qualified name, so you can safely omit the leading namespace separator. This is also true for the `use` statement.

```
namespace My\Namespace;
// Is exactly the same as 
namespace \My\Namespace;

use Foo\Bar as Class1;
// Is exactly the same as 
use \Foo\Bar as Class2;
```

In all other cases the leading separator ensures, that the given qualifier is absolut, if its missing, its relative. See [the manual](http://php.net/language.namespaces.rules) on how they are resolved.

If you use only classes from the same namespace and/or "declare" every class at top of the file via `use` (and maybe `as`), you can safely use relative class identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a difference, but not always (ah right).

In the `use` construct, you never have to 'mention' the leading `\`. Inline you never have to if the class is in the same namespace, or if you're using an import (imported with `use ns`).

But sometimes you must:

```
namespace foo;

class bar extends \baz\Bar {
```

You're using an undefined/unknown/unimported class inline, so you have to mention its source.

Another example is with unnamespaced classes used in a namespace, inline:

```
namespace foo;

$dt = new \DateTime;
```

A best practice (generally) is to import ALL classes the current file needs. A use statement is very, very, very, very cheap, so don't hold back.

```
namespace foo;

use baz\Bar AS OtherBar;
use \DateTime;

class Bar extends OtherBar { // or something like that; in this case (same class name) it's tricky
  function __construct() {
    $dt = new DateTime;
```

**edit 1**
Also, don't forget to use fully namespaced class names when passing them as strings, even though you might be in the right namespace:

```
namespace foo;

$class = 'foo\bar';
```

Comment: "in the use construct, you never have to 'mention' the leading \" : why ? (i'm just trying to put all the pieces together)

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Because `use` always works from the root. The leading `\` is implied, so unnecessary to type. It's a lot cleaner without. Wow, this reply is only 2.5 years late...

Comment: late reply is still a reply :)